# Enable/Disable Notification Window in cutom ROM

Tags: android, android-notifications

I am not a ROM developer but want to learn things. I am working on a ROM for LED TV. In this ROM the Notification Window is disabled by the factory. The ROM is running on some devices already. I want to turn the Notification Window on and also update the ROM of already running devices. I have the whole source code of ROM.

What approach should I adopt?

- Does installing SystemUI application from open source code of Android
  into my ROM will enable and replace my Notification Window ?
- How can I update the SystemUI application in the already running
  devices to turn on Notification Window as the ROM is custom?

Advice from Android experts needed.

Thanks in advance

Comment: @Kedarnath Ok I will post there. Thanks

Comment: @Kedarnath questions related to development are asked here not on android.stackexchange.com